# $A = B\cdot p(A)$. Show $A$ and $B$ commute.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

A problem my professor sent out:

> Suppose $p$ is a polynomial with constant term nonzero. Suppose
>   $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A=B\cdot p(A)$. Show that $A$ and
>   $B$ commute.

This is a generalization of the problem: suppose $A + B = AB$. Show $A$ and $B$ commute. Here we can note that $(I-A)=(I-B)^{-1}$. I've been trying to adapt that strategy to the more general case, without luck so far.

Comment: The ring on which the polynomial is defined is the matrix ring or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @marcotrevi $p\in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: My answer was completely wrong, my apologies (there was a terrible computation error). I'm a bit surprised that eight people upvoted it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note first that if a matrix $M$ is invertible, the use of the characteristic polynomial show that $M^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $M$.

Now we show that $p(A)$ is invertible. Let $x$ such that $p(A)x=0$. Then we get $Ax=Bp(A)x=B0=0$, and then that $ax=0$, where $a$ is the non zero constant term of $p(X)$, because $A^mx=0$ for all $m\geq 1$. Hence $x =0$, and $p(A)$ is invertible. Now apply the remark with $M=p(A)$: $M^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $M$, hence in $A$, and $B=AM ^{-1}$ is   also a polynomial in $A$. Hence $B$ commute to $A$.

Comment: I agree that $M^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $M$. But can you tell me what you mean by "the use of the characteristic polynomial"? I know how to do it by Jordan Canonical Form and interpolating polynomials, and I wonder if there's an easier way to show it.

Comment: If $M$ is invertible, the characteristic polynomial has a non zero constant term: $M^n+a_{n-1}M^{n-1}+...+a_0I=0$ with $a_0\not =0$. Hence  $M^{-1}=-a_0^{-1}(a_1 I+\cdots +a_n M^{n-1})$.

Comment: Very nice!-----